# CSRF approach of tomcat(apache-tomcat-6.0.32) not working fine on firefox 14.0.1

Tags: firefox, tomcat, csrf

I am working on Security scan(to avoid cross site forgery) with the CSRF approach of tomcat(apache-tomcat-6.0.32) but I am getting following issue with firefox:
1.  Firefox is not supporting CSRF provided by tomcat in a proper way firefox creating multiple sessions.
2.  Whenever any exception (like JSP exception) comes on page. Firefox redirects it to CSRFPreventionFilter and this filter creates new session.
3.  Sometimes while traversing through application also CSRFPreventionFilter filter creates new session.

Answer (score 0):

The creation of an `HttpSession` is by design: the `CSRFPreventionFilter` uses an `HttpSession` object to store the nonces used to protect your URLs.

`CSRFPreventionFilter` only calls `HttpServletRequest.getSession(true)` and never invalidates the session, so it shouldn't be creating any additional sessions (or switching a session).

Note that recent versions of Tomcat will change the session id when crossing an authentication boundary (i.e. when you enter your username and password). This is a mitigation against a different kind of attack: session fixation.